# Windows app to add shortcut keys

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, windows, desktop-application

I am assigned to build an app for windows in which user can define different shortcuts to copy/paste different contents in editors e.g. ctrl+k to paste "abc" and ctrl+alt+a to paste "xyz" in any editor where cursor is placed. I have no idea to how to start for this sort of app.

Hope this helps:

[image]

Comment: Start by deciding which language to use and tagging that language specifically. Then you have to attempt something and give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: want to do in c#, actual purpose of app to help a user define his/her own shortcuts for pasting text contents e.g. user defines his command ctrl+shift+u to paste text "abcdef" after defining this command, whenever strokes ctrl+shift+u "abcdef" will be pasted in notepad or word pad..

Comment: You have to actually attempt something for us to be able to effectively help you. You can't just tell us what you want to do and expect us to complete the project for you.

Comment: i have added a pic with my question to understand my problem, please click "hope this helps" in question, and my apologies as i am unable to explain it clearly, please answer after viewing pic.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, even without the picture, but as @Hank said - this is not "write me a code" site. You have to show us what you have tried so far in order to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I want is to know how to get it started, and the solution is **AutohotKey scripting** :) - just few lines of code and work is done.